# Within ThreadPoolExecutor, how to get thread ids of the executing threads in AspectJ

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, aspectj

I'm using AspectJ to monitor my application performance. E.g. start time, end time, memory consumption, etc.

1. I have a threadpool in my main package with 4 fixed threads executing a particular function. I need to check the thread ids of these threads when the particular function executes. I have a pointcut on this method, but I'm not sure how to get the thread id.
2. I know that I can use the after returning advice and the get the returned object in my advice. Is there a way to get all the objects created in a method. I'm assuming I'd need an after advice. But I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: do you have log4j configured?

Comment: No I'm not using log4j. I have a separate package which has all my aspects within it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```java
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

There is really nothing special in AspectJ with regard to threading. Aspect code is executed in the same thread it was woven into.

If I do not understand your question correctly and the above does not answer it, please just update your question and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in order to make the audience see and understand what the point is.